# RedMine: Link to Wiki of another project does not work

Tags: project, redmine, wiki

I have two projects in Redmine and both have their wikis.

Is it possible to link the wiki page of one project to the wiki page of another project?

I ended so far with using of http links:

```
"Redmine web site":http://www.redmine.org
```

But I want to use relative paths like this:

```
[[sandbox:some page]] displays a link to the page named 'Some page' of the Sandbox wiki
```

The Examples are taken form Redmines official wiki page:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormattingTextile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also define a custom link text for wiki links without having to resort to plain textile links:

```
[[your-project:your-wiki-page|Relative Path in Redmine]]
```

Using this syntax, you get the advantage of colored links depending on whether the target page exists or not and correct links on case you ever decide to move your Redmine server.

This and other syntax details are described on the help page you can access by clicking on the small question mark button above most text fields or on https://www.redmine.org/help/en/wiki_syntax_detailed.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

You can just direct from Redmines `projects` folder:

```
"Relative Path in Redmine":/projects/your-project/wiki/your-wiki-page
```